# How to place marker on entered address in Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

String "newAddress" comes from a popup window where the user enters an address.
p1 contains the latitude and longitude of the address.
When the marker is placed, it isn't placed at the right location. For example, when Melbourne is entered, the marker is placed in Ecuador. What is wrong with my code?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap mMap;
Button addNew;
Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //BRINGS YOU TO THE POPUP SCREEN
    addNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
    addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, AddLocationActivity.class);
            MapsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String newAddress = intent.getStringExtra("address");

    //THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS WHEN NO ADDRESS IS ENTERED
    if(newAddress == null||newAddress.matches("")) {Toast.makeText(context, "address is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

    //THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS WHEN AN ADDRESS HAS BEEN ENETERED
    else {Toast.makeText(context, newAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> address;
        LatLng p1 = null;

        try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(newAddress,5);
            if (address==null) {
            }
            Address location=address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            p1 = new LatLng((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));             

            //Turning the coordinates into a string
            TextView coordtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coorText);
            coordtext.setText(onlyCoords);

            double latValue = p1.latitude;
            double longValue = p1.longitude;

            // Add a marker to entered address and move the camera
            LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(latValue, longValue);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLocation).title(newAddress));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLocation));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i shouldn't do

```
p1 = new LatLng((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
```

I had to do

```
p1 = new LatLng((int) (location.getLatitude()),
                (int) (location.getLongitude()));
```